# Postfix equivalent of Exim :fail: for virtual aliases

Tags: postfix, exim

I'm in the process of migrating an existing mail setup from Exim to Postfix, which involves multiple virtual domains (i.e. they're not tied to the machine name or local system accounts).

I've come across a few entries in `/etc/aliases` which look like this:

```
aliasname: :fail: Failure message
```

If I email `aliasname@example.org` I get a bounce with `550: Failure message`. Effectively these aliases are addresses which are no longer used but provide a slightly more useful error message instead of just deleting the alias.

Is there equivalent functionality available for Postfix?

Answer (score 4):

These can go in the [Postfix `access` table](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html).

For example:

```
username@       REJECT Go away, we don't want any
```

or

```
username@domain 550 5.1.1 Are you daft? Stop mailing here. They died in a fire.
```

But be aware that this will match *either* sender or recipient addresses, depending on when you call it from `main.cf`. To check the recipient address, add to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`:

```
            check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
```

It can filter on much more than email address, so you will probably have more than that to add to it.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I want - apart from anything else it means splitting the list of aliases across two files.